# Optimizing large MySQL query (73MM rows) for most recent event group by

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, query-performance

I'm trying to grab the most recent event for each 'lead'. I have created indexes and this query still will take well over 30 minutes.

```
SELECT  l.id,
        l.home_number,
        l.mobile_number,
        CASE WHEN l.soldprice < 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as sold,
        l.lead_date
FROM (
    SELECT  l.home_number, MAX(l.id) as id
    FROM lead l
    WHERE l.lead_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 52 WEEK)
    AND l.state NOT IN ('NY','AR','VT','WV','GA','CT','DC','SD')
    GROUP BY l.home_number) a 
JOIN lead l ON l.id=a.id;
```

My table indexes are below:

```
Table Non_unique Key_name Seq_in_index Column_name Collation Cardinality Sub_part Packed Null Index_typ    
lead    0   PRIMARY     1   id          A   63123648    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
lead    1   id          1   id          A   63266540    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
lead    1   soldprice   1   soldprice   A   14715       NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
lead    1   lead_date   1   lead_date   A   15351477    NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
```

And my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE lead
( 
  id                BIGINT unsigned NOT NULL, 
  lead_date         DATETIME NULL,
  first_name        VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  last_name         VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  hashed_ssn        VARCHAR(34) NULL,
  city              VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  state             VARCHAR(2) NULL,
  home_number       VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  mobile_number     VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  email             VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  soldprice         DECIMAL(5,2) NULL,
  requested_amount  INT NULL,
  time_zone         VARCHAR(5),
  camp_id           VARCHAR(9),
  leadtype_id       VARCHAR(3),
  hittype_id        VARCHAR(3),
  PRIMARY KEY       (id)                           
);
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I'm using MySQL version 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: Is there a relationship between `home_number` and `state`?  For example, "212-..." is always a NY phone number; I may be able to take advantage of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tl;dr You need a compound (multi-column) index.

**Pro tip:** Don't create lots of single column indexes unless you know you need them. They rarely help much in complex queries, and they slow down insertions and updates.

You've done a good job of using a subquery to winnow down the `id` values for the rows you want to fetch. Still, surely most of the time is going into your subquery, this:

```
SELECT  l.home_number, MAX(l.id) as id
FROM lead l
WHERE l.lead_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 52 WEEK)
AND l.state NOT IN ('NY','AR','VT','WV','GA','CT','DC','SD')
GROUP BY l.home_number
```

It's usually smart to debug subqueries, then join them into main queries.

The first thing to do is this: Create a compound index on `(lead_date, home_number, id)`.  Then run this simplified subquery, omitting the exclusion on states. This should be fast, because it can random access the dates, then use the index to handle the grouping, and a loose index scan to grab the max id values.

```
SELECT  l.home_number, MAX(l.id) as id
FROM lead l
WHERE l.lead_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 52 WEEK)
GROUP BY l.home_number
```

Next, try creating a compound index on `(lead_date, state, home_number, id)` and try your original query.  If it is reasonably fast, you're done. Your query will be much quicker.  Drop the first compound index.

But it might not be, because MySQL doesn't really do well with `NOT IN` clauses in high volume.

In that case, keep the first compound index and drop the second one, and move your state exclusion to your outer query.

That will look like this:

```
SELECT  l.id,
        l.home_number,
        l.mobile_number,
        CASE WHEN l.soldprice < 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as sold,
        l.lead_date
FROM (
    SELECT  l.home_number, MAX(l.id) as id
    FROM lead l
    WHERE l.lead_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 52 WEEK)
    GROUP BY l.home_number) a 
JOIN lead l ON l.id=a.id
WHERE l.state NOT IN ('NY','AR','VT','WV','GA','CT','DC','SD')
```

That should help.

http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a good reference for this kind of work.

Comment: Thank you @O. Jones. I will work on setting that up and report back with results for both, in case anyone runs into this in the future.

Comment: "because MySQL doesn't really do well with NOT IN clauses in high volume."  and NULL (if your data allows it) is neither `not in` nor `in` l.state... not that it likely matters here but the column did allow nulls...

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky query to optimize because of the conditions you have on your subquery.

As a general rule, you can use indexes to optimize some conditions, but only one range predicate or GROUP BY or ORDER BY.

But you have two range predicates and one GROUP BY:

- `l.lead_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 52 WEEK)`
- `l.state NOT IN ('NY','AR','VT','WV','GA','CT','DC','SD')`
- `GROUP BY l.home_number`

You can use an index on `lead_date` to narrow down the row selection. You can use an index on `state` to narrow down the row selection. Or you can use an index to help the query read in group order and try to avoid a temporary table. **But you can only have one of these three optimizations** in a given query.

The trick then becomes choosing which one you will prioritize. It comes down to how well each one improves your query given the distribution of data you have. That depends on your data, it isn't something we can answer. So you have to test all three cases using EXPLAIN or just run the query with profiling to see how much it helps.

Usually, go with the range predicate that narrows down to the smallest subset of rows. Then even though the other range predicate and the GROUP BY have to work without aid of an index, they only have to work on a smaller set of rows, so the total cost isn't so bad (hopefully).

Comment: Thanks, @Bill Karwin. I'm running two tests from the previous suggestion and will also add your try your suggestion of only picking one predicate in the subquery and move the other two to the outer query. I'll report back later today with findings.

Comment: I didn't suggest moving predicates to the outer query. You can still have them in the subquery, but they won't be aided by indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb and making some assumptions about the data.

```
SELECT  l.id, l.home_number, l.mobile_number,
        (l.soldprice < 2) as sold,
        l.lead_date
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  l.home_number, MAX(l.id) as maxid
            FROM  lead l
            GROUP BY  l.home_number
    ) a
    JOIN  lead l  ON l.id = a.maxid;
            WHERE  l.lead_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 52 WEEK)
              AND  l.state NOT IN ('NY','AR','VT', 'WV','GA','CT','DC', 'SD' )
```

and have

```
INDEX(home_number, id)
```

Assumptions:

- The subquery will be quite fast, thanks to the index.
- The Optimizer will run the subquery before looking at `WHERE`.  (If this fails, change it to `HAVING`.)
- The MAX(id) and "in the last year" are heavily related
- Each `home_number` is specific to a particular `state`.

Let us know if this gets the same results, but much faster.